# uicollectionView Cell not animating (swift4)

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

My code below works because it prints something in the log file. But when each individual cell is pressed nothing happens to the cell expect the statement in the log file being printed.

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 2, initialSpringVelocity: 2, animations: {

            cell.frame = self.theIssues.bounds
            self.theIssues.isScrollEnabled = false
            cell.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell)

            print("d")



        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCell` is supposed to be used for creating cells for items in your data source, not for getting the visible cell. To get a visible cell, use `cellForItem` (it is initiliazed by `if let`, because it can return a nil value - which should not happen in your case, but lets use best practices):

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? whyCollectionViewCell {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 2, initialSpringVelocity: 2, animations: {

        cell.frame = self.theIssues.bounds
        self.theIssues.isScrollEnabled = false
        cell.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell)

        print("d")

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

But know that I would strongly recommend you NOT to mess around with the cell's frame (`cell.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell)` is also highly suspicious) - it's the responsibility of the `tableView`. Especially since you are setting the frame to the bounds - this will mess up the origin of the cell, not just its bounds.

If you want to do some effect, I would rather animate the content of the cell (which you are responsible of laying out), or I would even consider taking a snapshot of the cell and animating that. Of course all of this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! whyCollectionViewCell
```

with cellForItem

```
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```